# which software to use to make a jukebox cd on ubuntu?

Tags: cd

I would like to create a jukebox cd that I can play into my car.
On Windows, Roxio software is used.
A jukebox cd is a cd that has several folders and a supported filesystem type (the cd player of my car can read the ones created by Roxio).
If I create a data cd using Brasero then the audio cd player of my car can't read the files. I suppose it has something to do with the filesystem type that is used by Brasero (data cd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
genisoimage -J -r -pad -graft-points dir1/=/path/files dir2/=/path/files dir3/=/path/files > /path/file.iso
wodim speed=8 -tao dev=/dev/sr0 /path/file.iso
```

I have tested the result and it can be played in the mp3 cd player of my car.

Answer (score 0):

May be the correct option for you is the 'Audio project' when using Brasero. When selecting the type of project in Brasero, select 'New Audio Project', then drag and drop the required audio tracks to the project folder and then burn the disc. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will create a conventional cdda disk not a jukebox.